# How to solve a recurrence relation with full history $ T(n) = n + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{2T(i)}{3i}$?

Tags: recurrence-relations, computational-complexity

I have to solve a recurrence relation with full history given as:
$$ T(n) = n + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{2T(i)}{3i}  \tag{1}$$

I tried to solve it using the method given [here](https://opendsa-server.cs.vt.edu/OpenDSA/Books/CS4104/html/Recurrence.html) and [here](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs473/sp2010/notes/99-recurrences.pdf) and expanded it like this:
$$ T(n+1) = (n+1) + \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{2T(i)}{3i}  \tag{2}$$

Subtracting $(1)$ from $(2)$ gives:
$$ T(n+1) - T(n) = 1 + \frac{2T(n)}{3n} $$

which can be simplified as $$T(n+1) = 1 + T(n)\left(1 + \frac{2}{3n}\right)$$

I am lost after that. Please help.

Comment: Is $2/3n$ meant to be $\frac{2}{3n}$ or $\frac{2}{3}n$?

Comment: @bipvan Can you check if my edits are correct and reflect what you were intended to say?

Comment: @peterwhy: Sorry for the confusion. It is 2T(n) / (3i) . So 3i is in the denominator.

Comment: @Gary: The edits are okay. Thanks for it.

Comment: @SammyBlack: Thanks. It is 2/(3n).

Comment: $T(n)=3n$ seems to work.

Comment: @Sil I assume that, according to $(1)$, $T(1) = 1+(\text{Empty sum}) = 1$.

Comment: Could be, or it could be for $n\geq 2$ and were simply not told the initial conditions. Given linear polynomial is just related to the last recurrence in the post.

Comment: Based on the last recurrence: For $T(1) = 1$, WolframAlpha gives [a closed form in terms of some fractional $\Gamma$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=T%5C%2840%29n%2B1%5C%2841%29+%3D+1+%2B+T%5C%2840%29n%5C%2841%29+%5C%2840%291%2BDivide%5B2%2C3n%5D%5C%2841%29%3B+T%5C%2840%291%5C%2841%29+%3D+1); for $T(3)=3$, WA gives the same $T(n)=3n$ from @Sil .

Comment: Hint: define $S(n) = T(n) - 3n$ and note that your final result implies $S(n + 1) = S(n)\left( {1 + \frac{2}{{3n}}} \right)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Some result from WolframAlpha, acknowledged later in this answer)

Inspired by the closed form given by WolframAlpha, from the given recurrence and the particular solution $T(n) = 3n$ mentioned by @Sil:

$$\begin{align*}
&&
T(n+1) &= 1 + T(n) \left(1+\frac{2}{3n}\right)\\
&(-)& 3(n+1) &= 1 + 3n \left(1+\frac{2}{3n}\right)\\
&\implies& 
T(n+1) - 3(n+1)
&= \left[T(n) - 3n\right] \left(1+\frac{2}{3n}\right)\\
\end{align*}$$

So for the $T(n)$ term,

$$\begin{align*}
T(n) - 3n
&= \left[T(n-1) - 3(n-1)\right] \left(1+\frac{2}{3(n-1)}\right)\\
&\vdots\\
&= \left[T(1) - 3\cdot1\right]\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{2}{3i}\right)\\
\end{align*}$$

I assume that, according to $(1)$ in the question,

$$\begin{align*}
T(1) &= 1+(\text{Empty sum}) = 1\\
T(n) &= 3n - 2 \prod_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{2}{3i}\right)
\end{align*}$$

---

Based on the last recurrence, WolframAlpha gives [a closed form in terms of some fractional $\Gamma$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=T%5C%2840%29n%2B1%5C%2841%29+%3D+1+%2B+T%5C%2840%29n%5C%2841%29+%5C%2840%291%2BDivide%5B2%2C3n%5D%5C%2841%29%3B+T%5C%2840%291%5C%2841%29+%3D+1):

$$T(n) = 3n - \frac{2\Gamma\left(n+\frac23\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac53\right)\Gamma\left(n\right)}$$

Using generalisations of binomial coefficient $\binom xy$ [with fractional $x$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Generalization_and_connection_to_the_binomial_series) and [using the gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Two_real_or_complex_valued_arguments),

$$\begin{align*}
T(n)
&= 3n - \frac{2\Gamma\left(n+\frac23\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac53\right)\Gamma\left(n\right)}\\
&= 3n - 2\binom{n-\frac13}{n-1}\\
&= 3n - 2\cdot\frac{\left(n-\frac13\right)\left(n-\frac43\right)\left(n-\frac73\right)\cdots \frac53}{(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)\cdots1}\\
&= 3n - 2 \prod_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{2}{3i}\right)
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Just a sidenote: from an asymptotic point of view, $T(n) = 3n + \mathcal{O}(n^{2/3} )$ where the implied constant depends only on $T(1)$. In fact, $\left| {T(n) - 3n} \right| \le \frac{{\left| {T(1) - 3} \right|}}{{\Gamma (5/3)}}n^{2/3} $.

Comment: WA also gives [explicit solution for all initial values](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=T%5C%2840%29n%2B1%5C%2841%29+%3D+1+%2B+T%5C%2840%29n%5C%2841%29+%5C%2840%291%2BDivide%5B2%2C3n%5D%5C%2841%29%3B+T%5C%2840%291%5C%2841%29+%3D+a): $T(n) = 3n + \frac{(T(1)-3)\Gamma\left(n+\frac23\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac53\right)\Gamma\left(n\right)}$